# How to find apostrophe in string using PHP?

Tags: php, string

I can't get to detect an apostrophe (') in a string. I tried

```
if (strpos($username, chr(39)) > 0 )
if (strpos($username, '\') > 0 )
if (strpos($username, "'") !== FALSE))
```

without luck. What's the right way of doing it?

Comment: Please provide a simple test-case. One of your solutions should already work. Are you absolutely sure it's an apostrophe? There are other characters that look like apostrophes.

Comment: can I ask why you are searching for `'` in the username?

Comment: I don't want to allow ' in usernames - Drupal allows it by default. Not good when you want to pass usernames in URLs or create filenames or directories that use usernames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single-quote is a special character. So if you want to use a single-quote within the [single quoted string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) you have to escape the single-quote with a backslash `\` symbol.

```
int singleQuotePosition = strpos($username, '\'');
```

OR

```
int singleQuotePosition = strpos($username, "'");
```

[PHP Manual: Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: bahh.. nope.  single quoted string means the string is within single quotes. *sigh*.

Comment: @yi_H : yep it is confusing in scope of current question, I'll edit title of link I've provided basically to reference single and double quoted strings

Comment: but this is answer is dead **wrong**, the OP posted a working solution.

Comment: @sll I don't understand? `"'" === '\''`. @yi_H is right. `$foo = "My test's string"; var_dump(strpos($foo, "'")); // int (7)`

Comment: sorry guys for the confusion, I was confused as well ;)

Comment: looks like the code worked but because the username is passed in through an Ajax call it messes up or removes the '

Comment: @Uwe Druckenmueller : yep this makes sense becaue passing the single quote character from a client to server is dangerous so all such symbols should be escaped by a intermediate framework/channel

Answer (score 5):

you listed this one, and it should work:

```
if (strpos($username, "'") !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another random guess: Maybe your single quote isn't really a single quote.

If so, you might want to try [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/mb_strpos) or [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to find the UTF-8 variations of that character:

```
preg_match("/'/u", $string);
```

Or even test with `/\p{Pi}/u` to see if it's another type of single quote doppelganger.

---

Another tip: instead of `strpos` and boolean result fiddling, try [`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr) if you just want to test for a character presence.